# Regular Expression for Numbers after KeyWord

Tags: ios, regex

I have String as `"red:124green:45blue:23"`.

I have to get values for red,green, blue.

The output pattern should as to be
`124` Only, So i can Assign this value to red String.

second the output Should be `45`,So i can Assign this value to green String and So on..

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: red:(\d+) but iam getting numbers along with string.

Answer (score 0):

```
red:(\d+)green:(\d+)blue:(\d+)
```

you can also used named groups:

```
red:(?<red>\d+)green:(?<green>\d+)blue:(?<blue>\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"red:124green:45blue:23";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

float red = [[arr objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
float green = [[arr objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
float blue = [[arr objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];

NSLog(@"%f     %f      %f",red,green,blue);
```